# php как заменить несколько значений в строке?

Tags: php

Есть два массива:

```
$needles = [];
$replacements = [];
```

в них передаются значения. в первый массив значения текста, во второй на их что заменить. Пробую заменить:

```
$html = preg_replace($needles, $replacements, $html);
```

в итоге получаю пустую строку.
 Версия Php 7, как будет правильнее заменить? $html строка довольно большая, может в этом дело?

Comment: так а какие $needles? Может там вся строка целиком матчится и заменяется на пустоту?

Comment: В доках написано `preg_replace($patterns, $replace, '{startDate} = 1999-5-27');` соответственно первым параметром массив с паттернами дложен быть, а не текстом

Comment: Думаю, проблема в том, что неправильно оформлены паттерны. Для возможности ответа на Ваш вопрос, Вам необходимо предоставить больше данных, например: какие строки лежат в обоих массивах, какую строку пытаетесь распарсить, что же все-таки в `$html`: пустая строка или `null` (который ведет себя как пустая строка, если к нему обращаться как к строке)?

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему, `preg_replace` заменил на `str_replace`.